# A very interesting geometry problem

Tags: geometry

[image]

I think the figure is comprehensive. So the question is: what's the area of A, B and C?

Comment: Depends on the curvature of the ellipses.

Comment: @JPi They are quarter circles.

Comment: @user131929 Have you tried anything already? If so, could you share your attempts so far?

Answer (score 4):

$A+4B+4C=1,\; A+3B+2C=\dfrac{\pi}{4},\; A+2B+C=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{3}-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right).$

The last one is the area of a circular segment.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $A+3B+2C$ is a quarter circle.  Draw a diagonal and you can subtract $\frac 12$ from this to get $A/2+B.\ \ $ You can find the coordinates of the corners of $A$ from Pythagoras-they are on the centerline of the square and unit distance from the corner.  This gives the area of $A$ as a square plus four circular segments.  Three equations, three unknowns.

Comment: @CalvinLin:  Right you are.  Fixed.  Thanks.